# Single Sign On in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-5.3

> How Single Sign On can be implement in Laravel 5.3?

I have to develop an application in laravel 5.3. The requirement is 
i have a main site having user management like accounts.google.com.
After register/login to this site i can access few other services(2 other site in laravel say child sites)

My requirement is, i can login to main site and need to access the another 2 service sites without login. The user login will be from main site only.
How this could be done in Laravel 5.3? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: did you find the solution? i was searching the same.

Comment: any solution to this?